# how to build kubernetes dashboard outside a cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have built a kubernetes cluster， and I want to deployment in my personal computer which is outside the cluster. I have find out that dashboard use kubeConfig to access kubernetes in cluster， so how can I do. Thank you all~

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes dashboard was designed to use it in the cluster, instead of it you should definitely check [octant](https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/octant), it uses your kubeconfg and works outside the cluster.

Comment: yes，I know it‘s design to use inside a cluster， but it’s very difficult for me to develop in the cluster because I can't use ide like goland. I think it maybe have someway to use outside the cluster. And now, I can pass the kubeConfig by creating a rest.Config,  but a new problem has display which refer the CSRF part in dashboard.

Comment: Did you check octant?